# Proving that if $A$ is infinite, and $A \subseteq X$, then at least one set of $X$ is infinite.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Here is the original question: Let $A$ be an infinite set. Prove that if $$A \subseteq X,$$ and $X$ can be written as $$X=\bigcup^n_{k=1}X_{k}$$ then at least one of the sets $$X_{k}\cap A$$ is an infinite set. 
My book doesn't make any mention of infinite sets and I couldn't really figure out to answer this question. It makes sense to me that for an infinite set to be inside another set, that set would have to be infinite too, but I am struggling with formulating a formal proof to show this.

Comment: The fact to exploit: A finite collection $\{Y_i\}_{i=1}^n$ of finite sets $Y_i$ has a finite union $\bigcup_{i=1}^nY_i$.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:** If $X_k \cap A$ is finite for each $k$, then $$A = \bigcup_{k=1}^n(X_k \cap A)$$ is finite.